# Using Retrieval Multiple Objects for another Retrieval in Active Records/Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Kind of new to Ruby/Rails, coming from c/c++, so I'm doing my baby steps.
I'm trying to find the most elegant solution to the following problem.
Table A, among others has a foreign key to table B (let's call it b_id), and table B contains a name field and a primary (id).

I wish to get a list of object from A, based on some criteria, use this list's b_id to access Table B, and retrieve the names (name field).

I've been trying many things which fail. I guess I'm missing something fundamental here.
I tried:

```
curr_users = A.Where(condition)
curr_names = B.where(id: curr_users.b_id) # fails
```

Also tried:

```
curr_names = B.where(id: curr_users.all().b_id) # fails, doesn't recognize b_id
```

The following works, but it only handles a single user...

```
curr_names = B.where(id: curr_users.first().b_id) # ok
```

I can iterate the curr_users and build an array of foreign keys and use them to access B, but it seems there must be more elegant way to do this.
What do I miss here?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you  have following models:

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :department
end

class Department
  has_many :employees
end
```

Now you can departments based on some employee filter

```
# departments with employees from California
Department.include(:employees).where(:employees => {:state => "CA"}).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Department in your example has a fk to employee, which is similar to what I have. But if I try something similar to what you wrote, I get: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: employees.days: SELECT name FROM "departments"  WHERE "employees"."days"

Comment: The SQL in the error message doesn't look okay as it is missing the JOIN clase. Did you forget to add the `include` clause?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's take an example of Article and Comments, instead of A and B.

A Comment has a foreign key article_id pointing at Article, so we can setup a `has_many` relationship from Article to Comment and a `belongs_to` relationship from Comment to Article like so:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Once you have that, you will be able do `<article>.comments` and Rails will spit out an array of all comments that have that article's foreign key. No need to use conditionals unless you are trying to set up a more complicated query (like all comments that were created before a certain date, for example).

To get all the comment titles (names in your example), you can do `<article>.comments.map(&:title)`.